# What anime had a scene where a guy was turned inside out by a monster in front of a girl

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember seeing the scene as a kid. Early 2000's. So the anime had to be from at least the 90's. I don't know if it's the same anime, but a mystical guy was carrying a naked girl as he hopped through the trees. I only remember the monster scene because the guy was trying to fight it despite the girl telling him to run. And when that guy died, she cries in the mystic guy's arms.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.